# Problem executing psexec

Tags: psexec

I am trying run below command

```
psexec \\remotemachine -u username -p password notepad
```

As per my understanding, above command should launch notepad on remotemachine,
but it doesn't happen.

Strangely notepad.exe process gets created(I saw the tskmgr of remotemachine) every time i execute above command but notepad doesn't show up.

Am I missing anything in the command

By the way I am using 64 bit machines and both machines are on same domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `-i` switch?:

```
psexec \\\remotemachine -u username -p password -i notepad
```

The `-i` switch is described as follows:

> Run the program so that it interacts
>   with the desktop of the specified
>   session on the remote system. If no
>   session is specified the process runs
>   in the console session.

The console session is what you would see on the physical screen attached to the machine. If you are using a Remote Desktop session and would like it to appear there, then first you need to determine the ID of the session in which you want the UI to appear, which you can see using Task Manager on the remote system (ID column of Users tab). Then you pass the ID after the '-i' switch as follows:

```
psexec \\\remotemachine -u username -p password -i 1 notepad
```

Omitting the session ID is the equivalent of specifying a session ID of 0.

Other switches are documented here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: Thanks for the rdp session id part. @gaddigesh You can also do -d. Of course, see the docs and understand the difference and use what you need.